# Java Graphics2D flicker only when using nvidia-* drivers (Ubuntu)

Tags: java

When using java Graphics2D to draw to the screen I am getting an all black window inside my JFrame randomly. It happens more often when I try moving the images I am drawing. I was using a JPanel and overriding PaintComponent and switched to a Canvas with a buffer strategy. I get flicker in either situation. BufferStrategy is set to 2. I am drawing using a SwingTimer every 40ms, I tried throttling this it makes no difference, even if set to a really high delay such as 4 seconds. This only happens when using any of the proprietary nvidia drivers on Ubuntu 20.04 with a GTX 1050 ti. I tried purging and reinstalling the drivers I tried all the available ones under additional drivers as well as installing from nvidia's site. If I use my APUs embedded graphics this issue doesn't arise, This issue also does not occur when testing on a laptop with embedded radeon graphics. Here is how I am drawing:

```
 bf = getBufferStrategy();
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) bf.getDrawGraphics();

        do {
            try{

                g.clearRect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());

                //Drawing Loading
                if(c.getLoading()){
                    drawLoading(g);
                }

                //Draw Login
                if(c.getShowLogin()){
                    drawLogin(g);
                }

                if(c.drawGame()){
                    drawGame(g);
                }


            } finally {
                g.dispose();
            }
            bf.show();
        } while (bf.contentsLost());
```

I tried changing power levels and openGL performance under nvidia-settings application with no luck.

[Edit] By the way java: openjdk 11.0.8 2020-07-14 on both machines tested.

Comment: I would suggest that this is a driver issue

Answer (score 1):

I feel pretty silly, I looked over the JavaDoc for BufferStrategy to see if I was missing something obvious. They include an example which has an inner do-while loop that checks if the buffer contents are restored so I changed my rendering loop to:

```
bf = getBufferStrategy();

do {
    
    do {

        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) bf.getDrawGraphics();

        g.clearRect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());

        //Drawing Loading
        if(c.getLoading()){
            drawLoading(g);
        }

        //Draw Login
        if(c.getShowLogin()){
            drawLogin(g);
        }

        if(c.drawGame()){
            drawGame(g);
        }

        g.dispose();

    } while (bf.contentsRestored());

    bf.show();
    
} while (bf.contentsLost());
```

So far no flickering.
Java Doc: [BufferStrategy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html)

[Edit] I spoke to soon.. I am still receiving intermittent flicker. If it helps these are my VM options: -Dsun.java2d.opengl=True -Xms256m -Xmx2048m
Without opengl=True its really bad constant flickering.

After closing Chrome, and detaching the Server side of the game from intellij idea I don't see flicker. I am chalking this up as my environment and not repeatable (Client is pulling 30% cpu max average 15%), hopefully.